# Getting a list of BuildFire plugin users from the Widget side

Tags: buildfire

I am developing a plugin that allows the user the post content that I am storing in an object in publicData. To identify the user that posted the data, I am storing the `_id` that is returned from `buildfire.auth.getCurrentUser()` in that publicData object along with the content of the post.

Is there a way I can access a list of the users of my plugin, then iterate through that to find the user with the corresponding `_id`? A list of the users of my plugin must exist somewhere, I just do not know how to/if I can access it.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend caching the user object's nonsensitive data. Remember, you have a bit more access to the logged-in user over fetching another user profile using the user id. https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Auth#buildfireauth-getuserprofileoptionscallback

Since the user profile picture URL is really an API, you don't have to worry about the user changing it since it will always return the latest. The other property I recommend you cache is the Display name (not the first name and last name) since that rarely changes as well. This way your performance wont suffer and you can do a lazy fetch for a distinct list of user ids an update them as needed. KNowing most wont need an UI updates since nothing changed